# How to build a format for email body with HTML sent with PHP

Tags: php, html

Trying to understand how to customize an email sent with PHP.  I believe its suppose to be done with basic `<html>` and tables.  What am I doing wrong in the `$message`area?

As of now I get this in my message area:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('payflow.php');

  $tranid  = $_GET['PNREF'];
  $email   = $_GET['EMAIL'];
  $billtofirstname = $_GET['BILLTOFIRSTNAME'];
  $billtolastname = $_GET['BILLTOLASTNAME'];
  $billtoname = $_GET['BILLTONAME'];
  $billtostreet = $_GET['BILLTOSTREET'];
  $billtostreet2 = $_GET['BILLTOSTREET2'];
  $billtocity = $_GET['BILLTOCITY'];
  $billtostate = $_GET['BILLTOSTATE'];
  $billtozip = $_GET['BILLTOZIP'];

  $to = $email;
  $subject = "ORDER #$tranid\n";
  $headers = "From: $email\n";

  $message = '<html><body>';
  $message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
  $message .= '</body></html>';

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Email works well, `$_GET` data is fine.  Just confussed on how to get the message area to read `<html>`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Good stuff in this doc...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per php document,

```
<?php
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma

// Subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// Message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Comment: Yep saw that in there.  I was missing the two headers "MIME" & "Content Type"  - Thank you